# Get the distance an Object must have to be in view-frustum

Tags: trigonometry

I want to move the grey box in the Z Direction (to the left) so that it fits into the view-frustum of my camera. I know the vertical field of view, which is 40. The box Height is 4.

What is the formula for that?

[image]

Comment: Oh men...i think i found it but i don't know how it exactly works and why it works:

**dist = height / 2 / Math.tan(Math.PI * fov / 360);**

Answer (score 0):

You need to give focal length also , $=f$ say.

Let the required distance be $x$.  From similar triangles

$$ x/ f = 40/4 = 10 , x =10 f $$